# Having trouble retrieving data from CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cllocation, ckrecord

I am having trouble fetching the locations from cloudkit. The location gets uploaded, but when I try to have them printed out and loaded, they aren't downloaded. I don't get any errors.

This function uploads the location to CloudKit:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.015, longitudeDelta: 0.015))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()//
        let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
        }
            if error == nil
            {
                print("Location saved")
            }
        event1 = locations
    }
```

This function fetches the locations from CloudKit:

```
func loadLocation()
     {
        let locations = [CKRecord]()
        let publicData1 = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        let query1 = CKQuery(recordType: "location", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray:nil))
        publicData1.performQuery(query1, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let locations = results
            {
                self.locations = locations
                print(locations)
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem exactly is? Is it creating `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from `CKRecords`? Is it displaying pins on a map?

Comment: Right now i can't create the CLLocationCoordinate2D. I also don't think the locations are being fetched at all. @grimfrog

Comment: The brackets are wrong in the save code. But you must know that cause what you have will not compile right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to do this I made a unit test, that passes:

```
//
//  CloudKitLocationsTests.swift
//

import XCTest
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import CloudKit

class CloudKitLocationsTests: XCTestCase {

    let locations = [ CLLocation(latitude: 34.4, longitude: -118.33), CLLocation(latitude: 32.2, longitude: -121.33) ]

    func storeLocationToCloud(location:CLLocation) {
        let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error saving locations: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Locations saved: \(records)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchLocationsFromCloud(completion: (error:NSError?, records:[CKRecord]?) -> Void) {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil){
            (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error fetching locations")
                completion(error: error, records: nil)
            } else {
                print("found locations: \(records)")
                completion(error: nil, records: records)
            }
        }
    }

    func testSavingLocations(){

        let testExpectation = expectationWithDescription("saveLocations")
        var n = 0
        for location in self.locations {
            let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Location")
            locationRecord["location"] = location
            let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { (records, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error saving locations: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Locations saved: \(records)")
                }
                n += 1
                if n >= self.locations.count {
                    testExpectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        }

        // do something then call fulfill (in callback)

        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10){ error in
            if error != nil {
                XCTFail("timed out waiting on expectation: \(testExpectation)")
            }
        }

    }

    func testFetchingLocations(){
        let testExpectation = expectationWithDescription("FetchLocations")

        fetchLocationsFromCloud(){ (error, records) in
            if error != nil {
                XCTFail("error fetching locations")
            } else {
                XCTAssertGreaterThan(records!.count, 0)
            }
            // do something then call fulfill (in callback)
            testExpectation.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10){ error in
            if error != nil {
                XCTFail("timed out waiting on expectation: \(testExpectation)")
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Note that you had case mismatch Location/location. Also, I am doing a subscript to set the field value.

Run this it works. Getting the location from the location manger callback has nothing to do with CloudKit so you should be able to plug this in as you require.

One other thing: I did turn on the option to allow you to query on ID field for the Location record type.

Comment: I am attempting to call the fetchFromThe Cloud function: loadLocation((error, self.locArray)) and am getting the error: "Cannot convert value of type '(NSError?, [CKRecord]?)' (aka '(Optional, Optional>)') to expected argument type '(error: NSError?, records: [CKRecord]?) -> Void'"  @Rob

Comment: Show me the code. Sounds like you are not doing the trailing closure right. Look at the way the test calls that method: it doesn't provide the completion as a param, but has a closure after the call. @Caleb

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to retrieve an array of `CLLocation`, try this:

```
publicData1.performQuery(query1, inZoneWithID: nil) { records, error in
    var locations = [CLLocation]()
    if let records = records {
        for record in records {
            if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
                locations.append(location)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a print("h") after the line "locations.append(location)" and it doesn't get printed so I'm not sure if its getting that far in the function

Comment: the "for" line is when print stops working for first time